# SQL SELECT SQL Server Management Studio Version

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to obtain the SQL Server Management Studio version the user is running on the local machine when firing queries. Can't find anything anywhere so far.

This is not what I need. This will only give the SERVER version but not the Management Studio client version.

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version Details'
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: The server knows nothing about the client. No query will ever return SSMS version. The about box is pretty much the only option you have.

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_sessions` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  Returns one row per authenticated session on SQL Server. sys.dm_exec_sessions is a server-scope view that shows information about all active user connections and internal tasks. This information includes ...CLIENT  VERSION ..., client program name, client login time, login user, current session setting, and more.  Might be what you're after...

Comment: That's disappointing but makes sense.

Comment: @xQbert SELECT * from sys.dm_exec_sessions returns "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" in column [program_name], but no columns resembles the version number. [client_version] says "7". But i use "17".

Comment: What about `client_version`?  What's in it?

Comment: Well, that's the only thing I could think of.  I knew there was a sessions sys object that had some info; but I guess not what you're looking for.  Guessing 7 is the driver version then.

Comment: @xQbert - if you looked at the documentation you yourself linked, you'd see that `client_version` is about TDS protocol.

Comment: In addition to it not being available on the server side, the obvious question is what you could possibly want to vary in your script based on the answer - in general, scripts shouldn't care about which client tool (let alone version) was used to submit them to the server.

Comment: I run a script which obtains the Data Dictionary (DDIC) from the SQL server and based on that information I prepare a dacpac/bacpac file which will be handed over. I need to know whether the SSMS version used is above a certain version number, because dacpac/bacpac is only available at a certain version of SSMS.